# Retrieving 100 times more pages than what is actually available in the space

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api, scriptrunner-for-jira

I am writing some code to print some information about a given confluence space and I would like to print some information about the pages. The problem is that the space only contains 403 pages.

[image]

When I use the following code, I get around 100 000 rows which is wrong since I should only be getting 403 rows. Here is my code. Anyone knows the problem?

```
import com.atlassian.confluence.pages.Page

import com.atlassian.confluence.pages.PageManager

import com.atlassian.confluence.spaces.Space

import com.atlassian.confluence.spaces.SpaceManager

import com.atlassian.sal.api.component.ComponentLocator

import org.apache.log4j.Logger

import com.atlassian.confluence.user.UserAccessor

import com.atlassian.sal.api.user.UserKey

SpaceManager spaceManager = ComponentLocator.getComponent(SpaceManager)

PageManager pageManager = ComponentLocator.getComponent(PageManager)

UserAccessor userAccessor = ComponentLocator.getComponent(UserAccessor)

def file = new File('D:/confluence/data/scripts/result.groovy')

def fileWriter = new FileWriter(file) 

Space space = spaceManager.getSpace("IWIKI")

String result=""

for (Page page : pageManager.getPages(space, false)) {

    if(page.getCreator()==null){

            result=result+page.toString()+",null"+"\n"

    }

    else{

            String userID=page.getCreator().getName()

            String fullName =userAccessor.getUserByKey(page.getCreator().getKey()).getFullName()

            result=result+page.toString()+","+userID+","+fullName+","+page.getLastModificationDate()+"\n"

    }

   fileWriter.write(result)

}

fileWriter.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fiewriter was inside the loop which was causing the problem

```
     import com.atlassian.confluence.pages.Page
import com.atlassian.confluence.pages.PageManager
import com.atlassian.confluence.spaces.Space
import com.atlassian.confluence.spaces.SpaceManager
import com.atlassian.sal.api.component.ComponentLocator
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import com.atlassian.confluence.user.UserAccessor
import com.atlassian.sal.api.user.UserKey

SpaceManager spaceManager = ComponentLocator.getComponent(SpaceManager)
PageManager pageManager = ComponentLocator.getComponent(PageManager)
UserAccessor userAccessor = ComponentLocator.getComponent(UserAccessor)

def file = new File('D:/confluence/data/scripts/result.groovy')
def fileWriter = new FileWriter(file) 

Space space = spaceManager.getSpace("IWIKI")
String result=""
result=result+"PageName;UserID;FullName;LastModificationDate\n"
for (Page page : pageManager.getPages(space, false)) {
    if(page.getCreator()==null){
            result=result+page.toString()+";null"+"\n"
    }
    else{
            String userID=page.getCreator().getName()
            String fullName =userAccessor.getUserByKey(page.getCreator().getKey()).getFullName()
            result=result+page.toString()+";"+userID+";"+fullName+";"+page.getLastModificationDate()+"\n"

    }

}
fileWriter.write(result)

fileWriter.close()
```